# Как в возвращаемом json изменить формат вывода даты

Tags: wordpress

По ссылке http://udeveloper.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=9 получаю json из записей. Дата там выводится в таком виде: 2017-12-07T20:32:21. Как изменить формат вывода даты и сделать например так: 07.12.2017 20:32:21 ? Можно ли вообще?

Comment: Можно ))) чего ж нельзя )

Comment: А есть информация как это сделать? Где почитать про это?

Comment: Вы же выкинули дату из выдачи )

Comment: А я вернул) но он в виде 2017-12-07T20:32:21 выдает. А хочется по русски) по нормальному

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тот пример, что я давал, добавьте такой код

```
function format_date( $date, $format = 'd-m-Y' ) {
    $date = new DateTime( $date );

    return $date->format( $format );
}

$_data['date'] = format_date( $_data['date'], 'd.m.Y H:m:s' );
```

**UPDATE**

Вот код вашего примера целиком

```
function format_date( $date, $format = 'd-m-Y' ) {
    $date = new DateTime( $date );

    return $date->format( $format );
}

function my_rest_prepare_post( $data, $post, $request ) {
    // Получаем данные
    $new_data = $data;
    $_data = $new_data->data;

    // Добавляем изображение записи
    $thumbnail_id                          = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    $thumbnail                             = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' );
    $_data['featured_image_thumbnail_url'] = $thumbnail[0];

    // Убираем ссылки из объекта WP_REST_Response
    $links = $new_data->get_links();
    foreach ( $links as $key => $value ) {
        $new_data->remove_link( $key );
    }

    // Убираем ненужные поля
    unset( $_data['id'] );
//  unset( $_data['date'] );
    $_data['date'] = format_date( $_data['date'], 'd.m.Y H:m:s' );
//  unset( $_data['date_gmt'] );
    $_data['date_gmt'] = format_date( $_data['date_gmt'], 'd.m.Y H:m:s' );
    unset( $_data['guid'] );
    unset( $_data['modified'] );
    unset( $_data['modified_gmt'] );
    unset( $_data['slug'] );
    unset( $_data['status'] );
    unset( $_data['type'] );
    unset( $_data['link'] );
    $title = $_data['title']['rendered'];
    unset( $_data['title'] );
    $_data['title'] = $title;
    $content        = $_data['content']['rendered'];
    unset( $_data['content'] );
    $_data['content'] = $content;
    unset( $_data['excerpt'] );
    unset( $_data['author'] );
    unset( $_data['featured_media'] );
    unset( $_data['comment_status'] );
    unset( $_data['ping_status'] );
    unset( $_data['sticky'] );
    unset( $_data['template'] );
    unset( $_data['format'] );
    unset( $_data['meta'] );
    unset( $_data['categories'] );
    unset( $_data['tags'] );

    // Возвращаем данные
    $new_data->data = $_data;

    return $new_data;
}

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_rest_prepare_post', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как до компьютера доберусь попробую.

Comment: Добавил код, но теперь вообще ошибку выдает когда перехожу по ссылке, чтобы посмотреть результат в json. Весь вод добавил перед unset-ами

Comment: ну нельзя же так совсем буквально Ну как вы вставляете одну функцию внутрь другой

Comment: Кинул полный код в ответ

Comment: Понял. Я вначале пробовал как вы написали, только в основной функции ничего не менял, а нужно было вызвать функцию изменения формата даты.